# How do I grant a user permission to use Hadoop via Kerberos?

Tags: security, configuration, kerberos, hadoop

I've setup Hadoop to use Kerberos (following the [Cloudera security guide](https://ccp.cloudera.com/display/CDHDOC/Configuring+Hadoop+Security+in+CDH3)), 
but it is unclear how I connect to hadoop with regular users (e.g. 
username=myuser).

Currently I have myself authenticated with Kerberos with my Keberos 
admin user (via `kinit kerbadmin/admin`), but that doesn't seem to 
help.  Do I need to tell Hadoop that kerberos user "kerbadmin" is 
allowed to use Hadoop?

Running something like `hadoop fs -ls /` results in a permission 
issue:

```
11/09/13 11:13:03 WARN ipc.Client: Exception encountered while connecting to the server : javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)]
Bad connection to FS. command aborted. exception: Call to <myservername>/127.0.1.1:54310 failed on local exception: java.io.IOException: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)]
```

Also, `sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -ls /` returns the same error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just noticed an [appendix in Cloudera's setup guide](https://ccp.cloudera.com/display/CDHDOC/Appendix+A+-+Troubleshooting#AppendixA-Troubleshooting-Problem2%3AJavaisunabletoreadtheKerberoscredentialscachecreatedbyversionsofMITKerberos1.8.1orhigher.) that points out there is a known bug with Kerberos that is causing this, so the fix is to run `kinit -R` after authenticating with the server